# Rails problem find by sql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have this query and I have an error:

```
images = Image.find_by_sql('PREPARE stmt FROM \'
  SELECT *
  FROM images AS i
  WHERE i.on_id = 1 AND i.on_type = "profile"
  ORDER BY i.updated_at
  LIMIT ?, 6\
'; SET @lower_limit := ((5 DIV 6) * 6);  EXECUTE stmt USING @lower_limit;')
```

> Mysql::Error: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET @lower_limit := ((5 DIV 6) *
>   6);  EXECUTE stmt USING @lower_limit'
>   at line 1: PREPARE stmt FROM ' SELECT
>   * FROM images AS i WHERE i.on_id = 1 AND i.on_type = "profile" ORDER BY
>   i.updated_at LIMIT ?, 6'; SET
>   @lower_limit := ((5 DIV 6) * 6); 
>   EXECUTE stmt USING @lower_limit;

EDIT:
after finding the answer to: [MySQL: I need to get the offset of a item in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566620/mysql-i-need-to-get-the-offset-of-a-item-in-a-query) i need another help here to port it to rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you might not be allowed to use semicolon-delimited query sets in `find_by_sql`. Try finding a way to just use the happy Rails `find` method (see @Sleepycat's answer, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Is it just choking on the quotes? I am assuming that statement runs ok on mysql already. Try this:

```
Image.find_by_sql("PREPARE stmt FROM \'
  SELECT *
  FROM images AS i
  WHERE i.on_id = 1 AND i.on_type = 'profile'
  ORDER BY i.updated_at
  LIMIT ?, 6\
'; SET @lower_limit := ((5 DIV 6) * 6);  EXECUTE stmt USING @lower_limit;")
```

Comment: I got this error now

Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'profile'
  ORDER BY i.updated_at
  LIMIT ?, 6'; SET @lower_limit := ((5 DIV 6) *' at line 1: PREPARE stmt FROM '
  SELECT *
  FROM images AS i
  WHERE i.on_id = 1 AND i.on_type = 'profile'
  ORDER BY i.updated_at
  LIMIT ?, 6'; SET @lower_limit := ((5 DIV 6) * 6);  EXECUTE stmt USING @lower_limit;

Comment: now this:

Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'profile' ORDER BY i.updated_at LIMIT ?, 6'; SET @lower_limit := ((5 DIV 6) * 6);' at line 1: PREPARE stmt FROM ' SELECT * FROM images AS i WHERE i.on_id = 1 AND i.on_type = 'profile' ORDER BY i.updated_at LIMIT ?, 6'; SET @lower_limit := ((5 DIV 6) * 6);  EXECUTE stmt USING @lower_limit;

Answer (score 0):

I figured I would make a new answer because I ran out of space in the comment. 
I think you might be making life complicated for yourself with that statement. I am pretty sure you can achieve the effect you are looking for with less pain with a regular Rails find statement. It will be more portable (across databases) as well. I don't really understand whats going on in there but something like this:

```
Image.find :all, :conditions => ["on_id = :on_id and on_type = :on_type", {:on_id => 1, :on_type => "profile"}], :order => "updated_at" :limit => (whatever calculation you are using to get your limit)
```

The syntax might be a little off but it should get you in the ball park. In general you should be trying to keep logic out of the database and in your models.

Comment: If you are using the find I wrote, the calculation is done in Ruby and only the result is passed to the database. :limit => 2+2 will pass "limit 4" to the database. Its not the database that is adding 2 to 2, its Ruby. That find will work on any version of any database that Rails supports.

Comment: but then I get the same problem as before, how do i get the offset of a item in a query, ordered by updated_at? is not by id, remember.
The limit is always 6, the offset changes.
Here is explained the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566620/mysql-i-need-to-get-the-offset-of-a-item-in-a-query